# Appending specific JS object value to the div it was clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have some categories (titled stuff like "Animals" and "Misc") and clicking on a category opens a modal---ideally I want the modal to also show the category title. How can I append a specific JS obj value to the modal it was clicked on? For instance, clicking on the category titled "Animals" opens a modal and the title "Animals" should appear in the modal as well.

```
// creating the category divs
let $host = $("#host");
for (var i = 0; i < categs.length; i++) {
  let $template = $("#template").clone();
  $template.find(".cat-box > .cat-title").text(categs[i].Title);
  $host.append($template.html());
}

$("#modal-id").on("show.bs.modal", function(evt) {

  let title = _categories.map(function(val) {
    return val.Title;
  })

  $(".modal-title").empty();
  $(".modal-title").text(title); // ----- This shows everything, [0] shows the first item...can I get [i] to work?
  console.log(title);
})
```

#### console.log:

```
[object Array]["Animals", "Colors", "Miscellaneous", "New York Bo...", "Sports", "World Capit..."]
```

Comment: Where and how do you handle the "click" event?

Comment: Add an attribute `data-category=...` to clickable elements, then read it through `evt. relatedTarget` (i presumed you are using Bootstrap)

Comment: I believe $(".modal-title").html(title); should do the trick but i'm can't test it atm.

Answer (score 1):

If you open modal with (or similar):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-category="My Category Name">
    My Category Name
</button>
```

then in your modal show event:

```
$("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(evt) {

  let title = $(evt.relatedTarget).data('category');

  $(".modal-title").empty();
  $(".modal-title").text(title);

  console.log( title );

});
```

Basically, you set an arbitrary `data-` attribute with the data you need to pass to the modal and then you read it when event `show.bs.modal` is fired.

`evt.relatedTarget` give you the HTML of the invoker element, so you can use jQuery `.data()` method to easily get desired value.

Full working example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyNgjx?editors=1010

### UPDATED

I made some corrections (my version is slightly modified, but the logic is the same): https://jsfiddle.net/18Lb9caj/

Mainly, I removed the same ID in the cloned elements: you shouldn't use same ID on several DOM elements in the same page.

Then I used a different approach to filter out elements with jQuery.

Comment: Hi @atx, since my data is coming in via axios, would I set the `data-` dynamically like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wcbufavy/1/

Comment: @Bodrov you can add `data-category` to clickable elements when you generate them. So: 

1) get your data via axios
2) loop values
3) inside the loop: build your clickable element AND add `data-category=item.Title`
4) print output

Comment: @Bodrov i made some corrections (my version is slightly modified, but the logic is the same): https://jsfiddle.net/18Lb9caj/

Mainly, I removed the same ID in the cloned elements: you shouldn't use same ID on several DOM elements in the same page.